# Is it possible to get a different outcome on two different computers when multiplying two REALs in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I have developed some code on my computer and am now running the exact same code on a cluster and I'm comparing the results. Since I'm computing a very large array and I'm not writing it to a file, I'm computing a hash function (Adler32) to compare the resulting arrays.

Somewhere in the code I execute: `SUP = (YPL*ELOG) + 1./(YPL*ELOG)`. When writing just `YPL` to an array and computing the hash it's the same in both cases, and the same goes for the `ELOG`. But when multiplied, it gives different answers. All listed variables are REALs.

I compile the script with exactly the same compile flags, except for an extra compile flag `-mcmodel=large` on the cluster. However, the cluster uses gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) and on my computer I'm using gcc version 7.1.0 (Homebrew GCC 7.1.0).

Comment: It depends on the compiler flags. What are you using? Also, what real kind are you using?

Comment: As an easy check, revert to `-O0` if possible, and then run the same test.

Comment: I used just `-O3` but the difference stays. In both systems the reals comprise 4 bytes.

Comment: Please show us the exact numbers that are multiplied and the exact numbrs. Also, preferably a [mcve] that we can test.